# Sum occurence of mismatches in dataframe row- R

Tags: r

My example data looks like this:

```
df <- data.frame(a = c(".", "X", ".", "Y", "."),
                  b = c(".", ".", ".", ".", "."),
                  c = c("A", ".", "Y", "X", "T"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

I'm trying to count the number of characters that do not match either "." or "X" for each column of the data frame. These are the only two characters I'm trying to ignore.
I tried the following:

```
counts <- apply(df, 2, function(x) sum(x != "." | x != "X"))
```

That yields:

```
> counts
a b c 
5 5 5
```

Instead, I was expecting:

```
a b c
1 0 3
```

Can anyone advise?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be an `&` operation instead of `|` because `|` returns TRUE in 3 cases (`TRUE|TRUE`, `TRUE|FALSE` `FALSE|TRUE`).  As the first expression `df != "."` returns TRUE for all elements other than `.` and second TRUE for elements other than 'X', the `|` returns the full count i.e. the total number of rows as TRUE.

It can be made more efficient with `colSums`

```
colSums(df != "."& df != "X")
#a b c 
#1 0 3
```

---

Or using the OP's code

```
apply(df, 2, function(x) sum(x  != "." & x != "X"))
#a b c 
#1 0 3
```

Or if there are more elements, use `%in%` and negate (`!`) to change TRUE -> FALSE and FALSE -> TRUE

```
apply(df, 2, function(x) sum(! x %in% c(".", "X")))
# a b c 
#1 0 3
```

Answer (score 3):

I think this solution might be of interest to you:

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

df %>%
  summarise(across(a:c, ~ sum(str_detect(., "\\.|X", negate = TRUE)))) 

  a b c
1 1 0 3
```

Comment: I would recommend removing `!` before `str_detect` and changing the value of `negate` argument to `TRUE` to further simplify your code.

Comment: @Ashirwad  You are right, thank you very much, I really appreciate that. I edited my code.